# Permission denied when creating bitmap from photo path

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to create bitmap from photo path like this:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
```

And I have added permissions in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It works fine before. But suddenly it got a problem, says:

```
    E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/image_1.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I have been searching the answer for a few days, but still can not figure it out. I am totally new to android and this is my first post. Hope you can help me with it. Thanks!

For your reference, I am using android studio and genymotion. The app API is 23.

Comment: root your emulator. it's not letting you read the file.

Comment: Maybe permissions for reading file form SD cards changed in Android versions? Check if you are targetting for the right Android API Level.

Comment: For 23 you have to implement run time permissions too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission

Comment: @Shark I tried to restart everything. But the problem is still there. It is the run time permission problem.

Comment: Ah, API 23. yea, you need to request the permission at runtime and **do** if you get it or **bail out** if you don't. :/

Comment: @AhmetIpkin Yes, beginning from API 23, it needs to request runtime permission. Just learned from the accepted answer. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @VivekMishra yea, thank you. It helps!

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, get it! I should have searched more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app has not been approve for the permission to write to the external memory, this is a new feature for android 23 Marshmallow called [Run time permission](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

You first need to create a runtime permission for user to accept and approve to write to the external memory before you can write to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
```

to

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file://"+mCurrentPhotoPath);
```

I hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: After applying @Rod_Algonquin answer, I tried your suggestion by curiosity. Turns out it results in a "ENOENT (No such file or directory) error.